How to achieve list partitioning in Azure Postgres flexible server?
I'm using Azure Postgres flexible server and now I want to implement table partition by several values in a column. I went through pg_partmen(v4.7.1) extension docs and seems it doesn't support list partitioning.
Versions I'm using,

Postgres: v15
pg_partman: v4.7.1 (This is the version Azure currently supports)

Use-case: Assume there is a Postgres table called "Employee" like below and want to implement partition by country. Currently the Employee table is having millions of records and I want to improve the performance.
Employee Table



employee_id
first_name
last_name
email
country




1
John
Doe
john.doe@example.com
USA


2
Jane
Smith
jane.smith@example.com
Canada


3
Michael
Johnson
michael.johnson@example.com
UK


4
Emily
Brown
emily.brown@example.com
Australia



How can I achieve that on Azure Postgres flexible server?
